# При добавлении новых строк в таблицу не срабатыет скрипт получения значения input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуте. Вопрос такой. Я делаю добавление новых строк в таблицу на форме по кнопке "Добавить". в таблице инпуты цена и количство. мне надо вычислить сумму. Для первой строки таблицы сумма вычисляется, но для строчек, которые появились по кнопке добавить, скрипт вычисления суммы уже не срабатывает. понимаю, что ошибка кроется где-то в name новых строк, но не разберусь без помощи профессионалов
HTML

```
<form  action="index.php" method="post">
   <table id="table1" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th >№ п/п</th>
                <th >Номенклатура</th>
                <th >Количество</th>
                <th >Цена</th>
                <th >Сумма</th>
                <th ></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr >
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <select data-placeholder="Номенклатура" class="form-control chosen-select" tabindex="2">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="Номенклатура 1">Номенклатура 1</option>
                                <option value="Кофе">Кофе</option>
                                <option value="Кола">Кола</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>                   
                        <td><input name="quantity" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input name="price" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input name="total" type="text" class="form-control" readonly></td>

                        <td><button type="button" id="DelRow" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">-</button></td> 

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        </div>          
    </table>

        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Комментарий">
        <button type="button" id="AddRow" class="btn btn-primary " style="margin: 1%">Добавить</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin: 1%">OK</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var row = '<tr><td></td><td><select data-placeholder="Номенклатура" class="form-control chosen-select" tabindex="2"><option value=""></option><option value="Номенклатура 1">Номенклатура 1</option><option value="Кофе">Кофе</option><option value="Кола">Кола</option></select></td><td><input name="quantity" type="text" class="form-control"></td><td><input name="price" type="text" class="form-control"></td><td><input name="total" type="text" class="form-control" readonly></td><td><button type="button" id="DelRow" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">-</button></div></td></tr>' 
//тут создаю переменную строки с такими же атрибутами и стилями

        $('#AddRow').click(function(){
            $('tbody').append(row);    //Добавление строки

            $('table td:first-child').each(function (i) {
                $(this).html(i+1);    //Порядковый номер строки
        });
        });

        $('#table1').on('click','#DelRow',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //Удаление строки
            });

        $('input[name="price"], input[name="quantity"]').keyup(function(){
            $('input[name="total"]').val(parseInt($('input[name="price"]').val())*parseInt($('input[name="quantity"]').val()));
        }); // вычисление значения поля "Сумма"
});

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kley/fphfkgn5/1/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте так:
http://jsfiddle.net/11111000000/jym2e8mg/1/

```
   $('#table1').on('keyup','input[name="price"],input[name="quantity"]', function(){
```

и далее:

http://jsfiddle.net/11111000000/jym2e8mg/2/

```
function(ev){ 
   var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    tr.find('input[name="total"]').val(parseInt(tr.find('input[name="price"]').val())*parseInt(tr.find('input[name="quantity"]').val()));
}
```

Comment: Работает неправильно.

Comment: что конкретно неправильно?

Comment: во всех новых строках сумма из первой строки

Comment: @Kley, это ваш кривой код :P

Comment: @Visman, почему кривой? подправьте

Comment: так работает:
http://jsfiddle.net/11111000000/jym2e8mg/2/

Comment: @11111000000, дополните ответ решением.

Comment: готово, дополнил

Comment: @Kley: да, ради блага существ, попробуйте Ractive (http://ractivejs.org/) - он очень простой, быстро разберётесь и такие задачки будете как орешки решать

Comment: @11111000000, всегда пишите в функции `parseInt()` второй аргумент, тем более когда берется значение из DOM-объекта, никто не застрахован от некорректного значения.

Comment: Ваш покорный слуга лишь исправил оновную проблему автора, написанное тут никоим образом не отражает ни стиль, ни способы валидации, которые я реально сипользую, но спасибо конечно за совет.

Comment: ))) Всем спасибо за помощь и советы! Очень круто

Answer (score 1):

Строки нет в DOM - keyup на нее не повесится.
Надо использовать delegate:

> .delegate( selector, eventType, handler )
>
> Description: Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements
>   that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set
>   of root elements.

Должно быть что-то вроде

```
> $( "#table1" ).delegate( "input[name='price']", "keyup",function(){
>        var el = $(this).closest('tr');        el.find('input[name="total"]').val(parseInt(el.find('input[name="price"]').val())*parseInt(el.find('input[name="quantity"]').val()));   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/awzster/fphfkgn5/4/